# Koowa suddenly throwing strict errors

Tags: php, joomla-2.5, k2, error-reporting, koowa

Got a call from a client today who suddenly had these errors on the site, on Joomla 2.5.28

[image: Screenshot of errors]

Really interesting is - no one has made edits to this site in over a month, but these errors were not observed last week, and only started showing up this morning.

Even stranger still - System error reporting was set to **None**. It also appeared to have ground their K2 shop to a halt, preventing anyone from adding items to their cart.

I disabled the Koowa System plugin and everything seems to be working fine, including K2, but I'm very curious as to why this happened abruptly and if there's another way to address it.

Has anyone else experienced this or heard of it? Does anyone know of a reason why this could happen?

Comment: I've never encountered this error, but maybe your hosting provider  updated the default PHP version?

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting thought! Thanks for the idea I'll check on it.

Comment: If you are having issues other than "Strict Standards" warnings being displayed (like K2 not working), then there are other issues at fault. Warnings won't cause a site to stop working. Did you check the error_log? If so, were there any entries on or after the date the site started to malfunction?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar thing happen with a different component after upgrading the server's PHP version from 5.4 -> 5.5.

> Essentially, Strict Standards warnings are not errors; they’re messages designed for developers to help troubleshoot their software and such messages don’t need to (and it’s recommended that they shouldn’t) be enabled on a production site.

To remove the warnings,

1. Go to *Site -> Global Configuration* in the Administrator.
2. Click on the *Server* tab.
3. Set "Error Reporting" to "None" and save.

If that doesn't work, you can add the following line to your *php.ini* file:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL &amp; ~E_NOTICE &amp; ~E_WARNING &amp; ~E_STRICT &amp; ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Another option is to add `<?php error_reporting(0); ?>` to the top of your template's *default.php* file.

One of these solutions should work until the component's creator can make it "friendly" with your new PHP version.

---

References:

[Solving the Strict Standards: Non-static method Joomla error](https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/strict-standards-error-fix)

[How to Fix Strict Standards: Non-static method in Joomla?](http://www.balbooa.com/knowledgebase/32-documentation-faq-joomla/193-how-to-fix-strict-standards-in-joomla)

Comment: Sorry friend, that doesn't do it. As I said above, error reporting was already turned to none. I have the php.ini set up, still not working. Adding to the default.php is also a no go.

Comment: Which option doesn't work? All? I've seen instances where the Joomla! setting didn't have any effect, but changes on the server side did.

Comment: None of those worked.

Comment: Ok, in that case, I'm going to say it's definitely a server setting preventing error reporting from being disabled. Sorry it didn't work for you.